# Table with only ID and many junction tables

Tags: sql, database, symfony, doctrine, normalization

I am trying to design a database to be as scalable as possible, so I am testing the concept with a simple scenario.

Lets say I have a `contact` table.  A contact typically have an `address`, `phone number`, `mobile number`, and `email address`.

A single table can hold this information.  However, what if a contact has more than one of any of these details?  My solution would be to use junction tables like so:

```
contact -* contact_address *- address
contact -* contact_phone *- phone
contact -* contact_mobile *- phone
contact -* contact_emailaddress *- emailaddress
```

This would allow me to fetch all information about a contact.
In addition, the `address`, `phone` and `emailaddress` tables become data banks serving purposes from analysis to simply reuse of data.

However, I don't yet know what the performance implications are to this, and whether or not this is good practice, mainly because the `contact` table will only hold an `id` and nothing else.

One note is that this uses doctrine2, with symfony2 so writing long queries wont be an issue, my main concerns are those above, this has made a jump from one table to eight, and contacts is only one area I need to use a pattern like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine to use, you should not worry at all.

The only problem is if you allow Doctrine to lazy-load relations. Example:
if you

```
$contact = $repository->find(1) ;
```

and later in templates you do something like

```
{% for email in contact.emails %}
{{ email.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

this code will trigger another SELECT statement. Now if you display let's say 10 contacts per page, it means additional 10 queries will be executed.

Do the math if you display other things like address or phone numbers.

To avoid this lazy-load, you need to JOIN them in your query. Like

```
// ContactRepository

public function findForSomePage()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("o")
       ->leftJoin("o.addresses", "a")->addSelect("a")
        .... other joins ...
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
}
```

Now everything you need for display is fetched within 1 query.

Comment: Good point, I would have missed that.  I'll probably serialize the entities before they get sent to the templates to limit the chances of doing this by accident.

Comment: Do not serialize anything, there is absolutely no need to do it and honestly, I don't see a point of even doing it. Just check nr of queries executed in Symfony dev toolbar and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If a contact has more than one Address, you would not use a junction table, you would simply use a foreign key from address to contact.

I expect this design would most likely be more performant, although there are many factors to consider.

If an Address could be attached to more than one contact, and a contact could have more than one address, then you would use a junction table.

Comment: @ElectricLiama `If an Address could be attached to more than one contact, and a contact could have more than one address, then you would use a junction table.`

Its an occasional possibility, but it is one that if I don't account for now, I could run into problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use table inheritance.

Single Table Inheritance example:

```
create table address_type(
  id char(1) primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into address_type values
('t', 'Telephone Number'),
('e', 'E-mail Address'),
('m', 'Mailing Address'),
('w', 'Web Address');

create table address_role(
  id char(1) primary key,
  description text not null unique
);

insert into address_role values 
('f','Fax'),
('m','Mobile'),
('h','Home'),
('w', 'Work');

create table address(
  id serial primary key,
  type char(1) not null references address_type(id),
  telephone_number varchar(15) null,
  email_address varchar(320) null,
  web_address varchar(2083) null,
  suite_or_apartment text null,
  city_id bigint null references city(id),
  postal_area_id bigint null references postal_area(id)
);

create table party(
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null
);

create table party_address(
  party_id bigint not null references party(id),
  address_id bigint not null references address(id),
  from_date date not null default current_date,
  to_date date null,
  role char(1) null references address_role(id),
  telephone_extension varchar(5) null,
  primary key (party_id, address_id, from_date)
);
```